# Calculating Turbulence Spectrum

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

i got trouble with the evaluation of an hotwire signal. I am recording a hotwire signal (Voltage) in an windtunnel that measures velocity and even more important the velocity fluctuations. So from this voltage signal I can calculate the velocity signal - so far no problem. An important statement about the turbulence in the flow can be done with the energy density spectrum. Mathematically it is defined as

```
PSD = 2.0/N X*(f) X(f).
```

Were `X(f)` is the FFT, `X*(f)` the conjugate complex FFT and `N` the length of my sample. So what I did is:

```
def powerspec(x):
    s = np.fft.fft(x)
    return 2.0/N*np.real(s*np.conjugate(s))
```

Because this is not not leading to the right spectrum (compared to a given data set) I tried different methods like:

```
Pxx_den =np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))**2
f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs)
```

Each version gives an different result but none is the spectrum I need. Is there anybody that did this before and could help? The difference is shown in the plot below.

Thank you very much in advance!

The Signal and the data of the  "right" Spectrum can be found here: [Link to Files with Signal and Spectrum](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6x53ch11wd6hcq5/AACMZWZToyXJi40_Ky7mjH6Ma?dl=0)

[image: Difference between my try and the "right" solution.]

Comment: "not the right spectrum": You'll have to specify that. How do these spectra differ?

Comment: can you give a [mcve]? If I understand well I think you need to use `np.dot` to take the scalar product rather than `*` which does elementwise multiplication and returns an array.

Comment: By the way, that is **not** how the PSD is *mathematically* defined. What you gave was an estimator for PSD based on an observation of a weak-sense stationary signal. PSD is actually defined to be the Fourier Transform of the autocorrelation of the random process that you're observing. However, this renders the PSD something that is a property of a random process, not of a realization of the same; hence, that can never be directly observed from a signal, just *estimated*. See Wiener-Chintschin.

Comment: [*Wiener–Khinchin if searching English-speaking web sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener–Khinchin_theorem).

Comment: I added a plot that shows the difference. Damn, I have to get deeper into signal analysis. Is there any quick Solution you can provide?

Comment: @PaulR more latin spellings than letters in the original kyrillic writing.

Comment: The plots show different DFT lengths; I'm not convinced you're comparing them correctly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: indeed - the English wikipedia entry alone gives 4 alternate names - I just offered what seems to be the most common English spelling to help anyone who might want to Google it.

Comment: @PaulR sorry, didn't mean to criticize you; my wording was bad. Should have said "yes, but look out, weary Googler: you will encounter any combination of possible transliteration for Russian syllables"

Comment: Yes, i recognized the different DFT length. But i got no idea from what they are resulting. the input signal is exactly the same. I'll post a link to a dropbox with the data files if it is allowed here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added the link in the question above.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: no problem - I didn't take it as a criticism!

Comment: @user3573247 well, does your "reference spectrum" (which I don't trust any better than yours) have the correct length, or does your spectrum have the correct length?

Comment: good point. I guess my reference spectrum because this was used in a former phd thesis the way my reference spectrum was derived is described here: http://www.ni.com/example/30803/en/  The averaging parameters are exactly the same as shown in the example.  What would be your way of calculating the spectrum?

Comment: @all: I solved the problem. It was just a question of scaling. What I need is the Power Spectrum and not the Power Spectral Density.

Comment: You have mixed the power spectral density with the energy spectral density. Moreover, your definition for the power density spectrum is not correct and missing the time scaling.